# How to Recover from Fail State in MongoDB Ops Manager

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I upgrade `MongoDB Ops Manager` from `4.2.4` to `4.4.6`. Then it told me that `MongoDB Agent`, `MongoDB Tools` are out of date. After I press the upgrade button, the upgrade process is stucked.

The `Agent` log has the following error:

```
Interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not float64
```

Now the `Ops Manager` is stuck at the `"deploying"` stage. How to revert to the previous state or fix the problem?

`$ kubectl exec -it pod` - is useless as the pod are running under a `security context` which uses user "2000"
https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/reference/troubleshooting/
is almost useless as we don't have permission to change the pod state. So what's the right way to fix deployment issues when using `Ops Manager`?